# Firefox extension - add jsdelivr cdn

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am looking to get access to jsdelivr cdn ( or any other cnd for that matter ) in the html page.
From the research I have done this is being done in the content_script and content_security_policy but no matter no matter what I have done I still get the following error

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js (“script-src”).
```

here is my manifest and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "page": "my-page.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["https://code.jquery.com, https://*.cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/page-32.png"
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm;  object-src 'self'",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ]

}
```

Comment: No, 1) `content_security_policy` is for own extension pages like your my-page.html whereas `content_scripts` is for web pages, 2) only local files inside the extension directory/package can be specified in `js` key. Also pay attention to quotes: each value should be quoted individually.

Comment: If you want to add scripts to `my-page.html` then just use `<script src=file.js></script>` tags inside like you would do in any other html page. However, it's a bad idea to load external scripts into the privileged extension context since URLs can be redirected easily by a malicious proxy and such. Don't do that. Download the script into your extension directory and use this local version.